# What is the best way to calculate the accuracy of GPS point measurements in relation to the road network?

Tags: gps, proximity, accuracy

I have a vector dataset containing GPS locations/points of different vehicles and a (polygon) road network dataset. Due to the inaccuracy of the GPS receiver, these gps points can deviate up to 10-20 meters from the road network. What is the best way to calculate the accuracy of these GPS measurements in relation to the road network?

[image]

I was thinking of calculating the distance of each GPS point to the nearest road feature and average this distance to get the mean spatial variation for all GPS points. Is this the best method to determine the accuracy of the GPS measurements?